# How to get only the file name from directory rather than whole path in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
mainFile=$(find /home/INVENT/custREAD -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -mmin 300)
```

I m using the above line in my shell script to fetch the file from the location `/home/INVENT/custREAD` and put it in the variable `mainFile`

But when I echo this variable, I see:

```
/home/INVENT/custREAD/filename.txt
```

But I want that only the file name to be in the variable, because then I want to unzip this file with

```
  gunzip "$mainFile"
```

but this is causing an error

```
gzip : No such file or directory
```

Can someone please correct where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+file+name+from+path+%5Bbash%5D ?

Comment: @0s  No that didnt work for me. how can I put that method in the command that I have written ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU find, you can use `-printf` to drop the path:

```
mainFile=$(find /home/INVENT/custREAD -name '*.txt.gz' -type f -printf '%f')
```

This assumes that you'll find just one file, or else all filenames will be in a single string.

You could also use parameter expansion to remove everything up to the last slash:

```
mainFile=$(find /home/INVENT/custREAD -name '*.txt.gz' -type f)
echo "${mainFile##*/}"
```

It looks like you don't even need `find`, since you seem to expect just one `.txt.gz` file, so you could use a glob instead:

```
mainFile=/home/INVENT/custREAD/*.txt.gz
```